# Undefined Index Among Others

Tags: php

How can I fix these error(s):

```
Notice: Undefined index: authData in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/admin/classes/lib/SessionData.php on line 27 
Notice: Undefined index: authData in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/admin/classes/lib/SessionData.php on line 29 
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/index.php on line 16
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/admin/classes/lib/SessionData.php on line 26 
Notice: Undefined index: authData in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/admin/classes/lib/SessionData.php on line 27 
Notice: Undefined index: authData in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/admin/classes/lib/SessionData.php on line 29 
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /home/paulmc1/domains/kuarrel.tk/public_html/admin/classes/lib/Log.php on line 29"
```

CODE:

SessionData.PHP:

```
<?PHP

class SessionData{

    function __construct($page = 'default'){
        $this->SetSession($page);
    }


    public function SetSession($page = 'default'){
            $currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 

        $rootDomain = '.kuarrel.tk'; 

        session_set_cookie_params( 
            $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
            $currentCookieParams["path"], 
            $rootDomain, 
            $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
            $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
        ); 
        session_start();
        $this->authData = $_SESSION['authData'];

        if($_SESSION['authData']['accountstatus']=="-1" && $page=="default"){
        //echo $page;
            header("Location: account.php");
            //exit();
        }
            /*
            Currently Known Values

            $this->authData['email']        
            $this->authData['id']              
            $this->authData['name']       

            */

    }               

    public function Retrieve($name){
        if( in_array($name,$this->validSessVars()) && isset($this->authData[$name]) ){
                return($this->authData[$name]);
        }
        return(FALSE);
    }       

    public function RetrieveAll(){
        return($this->authData);
    }

    private function validSessVars(){
        $valid=array();
        $count=0;
        if(is_array($this->authData))
        foreach($this->authData as $key => $value){
            $valid[$count]=$key;
            $count++;
        }
        return($valid); 
    }


    public function Logout(){
            unset($authData);
            $_SESSION['authData'] = $authData;
            header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/index.php");
            exit();
    }

    public function Login(){
                unset($authData);
                $_SESSION['authData'] = $authData;
                header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/login.php");
                exit();
        }   

    public function CheckValidSession(){
        if(is_array($this->authData)&&$this->authData['id']>0){
            return(TRUE);
        }
        return(FALSE);
    }   

    public function CheckValidFBSession(){
        if (!$this->CheckValidSession()){
            header('location: bind.php');
        }

    }   


    public function CheckValidAdminSession(){
        if($this->authData['accountstatus']==9){
            return(TRUE);
        }
        return(FALSE);
    }   

}

?>
```

Index.PHP:

```
<?php

//Error Checking
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/admin/classes/classes.php');        // Include local class lib

$sess = new SessionData();      // Creates session object
//$sess->CheckValidFBSession();

if($sess->CheckValidSession()){         
    header('Location: home.php');
}

$log= new log($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ); 
$stats=new Statistics();
$totalusers=$stats->totalscope();

?>
<html xmlns:fb="//www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '<?php echo $sess->fbappid; ?>',
          session : <?php echo json_encode($sess->fbsession); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>


<title>Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel!</title> 
 <meta name="description" content="Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from throughout the world." /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="kuarrel, chaibear, chai, sa-mp, sa:mp, 2014" /> 
<meta name="Generator" content="JB engine designed" /> 
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
<meta name="OriginalPublicationDate" content="2014/03/12/01:37:22">
<meta name="Headline" content="Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel!"> 
<meta name="IFS_URL" content="/index.php"> 
<meta name="contentFlavor" content="PAGE"> 
<meta name="CPS_SITE_NAME" content="Kuarrel | Welcome to Kuarrel"> 
<meta name="CPS_SECTION_PATH" content="Index"> 
<meta name="CPS_ASSET_TYPE" content="STY"> 
<meta name="CPS_PLATFORM" content="HighWeb"> 
<meta name="CPS_AUDIENCE" content="US"> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Kuarrel is an  online directory that connects people from throughout the world."> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from throughout the world.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kuarrel.tk/images/logo-right.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kuarrel.tk/index.php"> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Kuarrel">
  <!-- sO3vWw3hwrnxdrwPGTKy2ZOW6yU -->
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    };
    (function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=194568130593245&amp;xfbml=1&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

<center> 
<table class="bordertable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=700> 
  <tr><td> 
      <table class="bottomborder" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%> 
      <tr><td width=350 bgcolor=#3B5998> 
          <img src='images/logo-left.jpg'></td> 
          <td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%><tr><td> 
          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%> 
          <tr><td><a href='register.php'><img alt='Register' src='images/logo-right.jpg' border=0></a></td> 
          <td width=100% bgcolor=#3B5998> </td></tr></table></td></tr> 
          <tr><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 border=0 width=100%><tr height=21> 
          <!--<td bgcolor=#3B5998 width=10> </td>--> 
 <?PHP

            if(!$sess->CheckValidSession()){            
                include('modules/default/topnav.php');
            }else{
                include('modules/loggedin/topnav.php');       
            }
            ?>                   <td bgcolor=#3B5998 width=100%> </td> 
          </tr></table></td> 
          </tr></table> 
      </td></tr></table> 
  </td></tr> 
  <tr><td><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 width=100%> 
      <tr><td valign=top> 
      <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=105> 
        <tr><td> 
 <?PHP

            if(!$sess->CheckValidSession()){            
                include('modules/default/leftnav.php');
            }else{
                include('modules/loggedin/leftnav.php');          
            }
            ?>
                      </td></tr>  
      </table> 
      </td><td width=595 valign=top> 
        <table class="bordertable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 width=100%><tr><td> 

<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0 width=100%> 
<tr><td class='white' bgcolor=#3B5998>Welcome to Kuarrel!</td></tr></table><center><p class='title'>[ Welcome to Kuarrel ]<br>
 <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=95%>
<tr><td class='larger'><?<img src="https://phpacademy.org/img/smileys/frown.png" width="18" height="18" alt="=(" title="=(" class="bbcode_smiley"/>!empty($_GET['error']));?>"<span style='color:red;font-size:16px;'>Facebook login has been disabled for today, please try again tomorrow.</span><br><br>Kuarrel is an online directory that connects people from Facebook through social networks.
<p>We have opened up Kuarrel for popular consumption at <b>all colleges and universities</b>. If you are not part of a college or university, you will be added to the default Kuarrel network.
<p>Your account is limited to your own college or university. 
<p>You can use Kuarrel to:
<br> <b>•</b>  Search for people at your school
<br> <b>•</b>  Find out who are in your classes
<br> <b>•</b>  Look up your friends' friends
<br> <b>•</b>  See a visualization of your social network

<p>To get started, click below to register with your facebook account.<!--<br><font size="+1">Join the <?=$totalusers?> people at Kuarrel today.</font>-->



<center>
<?php if(strlen($_SESSION['notpartofacollege'])>2){
echo "<b>".$_SESSION['notpartofacollege']."</b>";
}
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<center><input class='inputsubmit' type="button" value='Register' onclick='javascript:document.location="register.php";'>  <input class='inputsubmit' type="button" value=' Login ' onclick='javascript:document.location="login.php";'>
<br> </td></tr></table>  </td></tr></table> 




  </td></tr></table> 
  <center> 
  <?PHP include('modules/default/bottomnav.php');   ?>
  </center><br> 
  </td></tr></table>
```

Log.PHP:

```
class log{

    public function __construct($page, $get= '', $post = '', $ref = '') {

        $sess = new SessionData('account'); 
        if($sess->CheckValidSession()){ 
            $userid=$sess->Retrieve('id');
        }else{
            $userid="0";
        }

        if($userid=='45403199'){
            return false;
        }


        if(!$ref) $ref="";

        $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];


        $values=array('page'=>$page,'ip'=>$ip,'userid'=>$userid, 'timestamp'=>(int) time(), 'gets'=>$get, 'posts'=>$post, 'referral'=>$ref); 
        $m = new MongoClient();
        $collection = $m->selectCollection('kuarrel', 'log');
        $collection->insert($values);

        if($ip=='202.94.191.47'||$ip=='202.94.191.13'||$ip=='202.94.191.183'){
            echo "Your address: ".$ip." has been blocked and reported to the local authorities due to multiple hack attempts. Please contact kuarrelhelpdesk@gmail if you feel this is an error.";
            die(); 
        }
    }

    function lastpage($userid){
        $m = new MongoClient();
            $collection = $m->selectCollection('kuarrel', 'log');
            $cursor = $collection->find(array('userid'=>$userid));
            $cursor->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1))->limit(2);
            $records = iterator_to_array($cursor);

            return($records[1]['page']);
    }

}
?>
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: By googling for `How to fix Notice: Undefined index in php`, to fix your undefined index. Then I'd suggest doing a google for `Notice: A session had already been started` for the second type of error. I'll leave the solution of how to fix the 3rd type of error up to your imagination, but its solution is similar in nature to the solutions of the 1st and 2nd type of error. Once googling is complete, write/change small amounts of code, and voila. Errors fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple isset check for the existence of a value for authData in the session would fix this.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['authData'])){ 

      $this->authData = $_SESSION['authData'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] will not be set if you open the page directly.
So it's better to check it's value before using:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
  ...do something here
```

Also make sure you  set the `$_SESSION['authData']` before using it

Finally, `MongoClient` should be defined before using it. I don't see it anywhere.